# Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined for imported module

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

Here is scenario:

index.js

```
import test1 from './test1';
window.test1 = test1;
```

test1.js

```
import test2 from './test2';
var test1 =  (function (){
  var self = this;
  var x = {};
  x.test2 = test2;
  var testValue = 'TEST VALUE';
  let init = function(){
        console.log ( x.test2() );
  }  
  init();
  return {
    x: x,
    testValue: testValue
  }
})();
export default test1;
```

test2.js

```
var test2 =  function () {
    return (` value to use ${testValue} ` )
};

export default test2;
```

I am getting the following error in test2.js when running index.js
 **Uncaught ReferenceError: testValue is not defined**

is there a way to use testValue without having to pass it in?

Comment: Where is the testvalue coming from ???

Comment: And in  your test2.js you have to define what is testvalue

Answer (score 0):

you can transform test1 to a `Class Object`, then use `this.value` in test2, and it will use the value of test1's instance

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to use `testValue` without having to pass it in?

You'd have to make sure that it is set as global variable *before* the function is executed. But using globals is often bad design. Passing the value in is much easier to reason about. Since you are not explaining why you want to do that, that's all the advice I can give.